# Sharing a cluster with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, torque

Is it possible to set Hadoop up so that it plays nicely with other applications on a cluster?

I'm familiar with the Torque+Maui resource scheduler, and with using HadoopOnDemand to provision temporary Hadoop clusters. But that gets pretty cumbersome if lots of people want to use Hadoop: each person has the same headache of setting up and tearing down their own mini hadoop cluster, copying data on and off thier own HDFS, etc.

It would be much cooler if we could have one permanent instance of Hadoop running that people share, with an HDFS that is always up. This would require Hadoop intelligently allocating work to nodes that aren't busy with other applications (like R, say), and not being to greedy when queueing jobs.

Is this possible?

Comment: unfortunately i think this is somewhere Hadoop really lacks in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what the fair scheduler does?

http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/fair_scheduler.html

We use this to run a permanent hadoop cluster with 30 users. You can have it preempt tasks to reallocate to new pools, and can set individual priorities for each pool too.

Comment: Not quite, no. This works if the cluster is only running Hadoop, but what if people want to use it for other applications as well?